# Was Olly convicted for murder or for treason against Jon Snow?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Was Olly convicted for murder or for treason against Jon Snow?

If Olly killed Jon Snow, who comes back from life, does it still count as murder of Jon Snow?

Comment: 2 questions should probably be 2 separate posts, but as to #2: If someone steals your car, and the police find the car and return it to you, they still committed theft.  Similarly if you replace "police find" with "red woman revives", "steals" with murders, and "car" with "Jon Snow".

Comment: okey sorry, but do  you think he  was convicted for murder or treason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@Skooba](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/172382/58193) points out Jon seems to think it was murder. Here's a more explicit quote of it:

> DAVOS: You were dead. And now you’re not. That’s completely fucking mad, seems to me. I can only imagine how it seems to you.
>   
> JON SNOW: I did what I thought was right. And **I got murdered for it**. And now I’m back. Why?
>   
> <sub>Game of Thrones, Season 6 Episode 3, "Oathbreaker"</sub>

However, Ser Alliser Thorne appears to believe it is treason. He seems to think Jon committed treason by bringing the wildlings in but he also then committed treason by murdering Jon for it:

> ALLISER THRONE: I had a choice, Lord Commander. **Betray you or betray the Night’s Watch.** You brought an army of wildlings into our lands. An army of muderers and raiders. If I had to do it all over knowing where I’d end up, I pray I’d make the right choice again.
>   
> JON SNOW: I’m sure you would, Ser Alliser.
>   
> ALLISER THRONE: I fought, I lost. Now I rest. But you, Lord Snow, you’ll be fighting their battles forever.
>   
> <sub>Game of Thrones, Season 6 Episode 3, "Oathbreaker"</sub>

The [wikia](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Oathbreaker) for the episode refers to those who were hanged as "traitors":

> Some time later, Jon oversees the public hanging of the **traitors** responsible for the **Mutiny at Castle Black**: Bowen Marsh, Othell Yarwyck, Alliser Thorne and Olly.

It also refers to the event as the Mutiny at Castle Black and a mutiny is by definition treason.

Lastly, the title of the episode where Jon sentences them is called "Oathbreaker", it seems this is multilayered to refer to quite a few things but one of those were the traitors. By breaking an oath you are effectively committing treason. Note that Jon is also a main target for the episode name seeing as he let the wildlings in and then left the watch, i.e. he broke his oath.

Comment: so you would say it was for treason and not murder?

Comment: @Vojb- Different characters voice it as different things but murder is effectively treason in this scenario, it's essentially both.

Answer (score 10):

Jon seems to think it was murder (which in turn would be treason).

When Jon gives the betrayers a chance for last words Yarwyck says;

> You shouldn't be alive, it's not right.

To which Jon responds;

> Neither was killing me.